# What does `const T* const` mean?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I was reading a C++ template example, and part of the template signature confused me.

Am I reading this correctly:

```
const T* const foo;
```

Is `foo` a `const*` to a `const T`?

Comment: foo should be initialized on the line where it is declared, because once foo is brought to life, it can not be changed because it is constant.

Comment: Read it from right to left: foo is a `const *` to a `const T`. So you are correct!

Comment: @bert-jan, not quite true. This could, for instance be set in the initializer list of a constructor. I can't think of anything else, though.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it's a constant pointer to a constant `T`. I.e., you can neither modify the pointer, nor the thing it points to.

`const T*` would only forbid you to modify anything the pointer points to, but it allows you (within the bounds of the language) to inspect the value at `*(foo+1)` and `*(foo-1)`. Use this form when you're passing pointers to immutable arrays (such as a C string you're only supposed to read).

`T * const` would mean you can modify the `T` value pointed to by `foo`, but you cannot modify the pointer itself; so you can't say `foo++; (*foo)++` because the first statement would increment (modify) the pointer.

`T *` would give you full freedom: you get a pointer into an array, and you can inspect and modify any member of that array.

Comment: In the last example T const * what would be the type of pointer? I presume whatever came after '*'? I also presume it means a const pointer (of some type) pointing to a non-const type T?

Comment: @user997112: typo, sorry. It should have been `T * const`. That means, reading from right to left, constant pointer to `T`. You can modify the value it points to, but not the pointer itself, so you can't modify adjacent parts of memory.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: typo, fixed. Thanks!

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: in the case of a `const T*`? No, you could *inspect* those values. Modifying them would require casting the `const` off.

Comment: @Benjamin, so you're saying *(foo+1) is allowed but (*foo) +1 isn't allowed?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: ah, sorry for the confusion. Updated that bit, is it clearer this way?

Comment: @user997112: `(*foo) +1` is allowed in any case. But `(*foo)++` is not *when the value is `const`* (no matter if the pointer is `const` or not).

Comment: @larsman, ah- i think I get you. Is that because the value of (*foo)+1 would be assigned to another variable (and not changing the value of foo) whereas (*foo)++ would actually be incrementing the value of foo itself?

Comment: +1 The second upvote to an answer on this question, 37 minutes later. :)

Comment: @user997112: You're touching on delicate terminology here :) Adding one with `(*foo)+1` would be allowed for `T *const foo` because it just produces a value (not a variable!), while `(*foo)++` would modify the value pointed to by `foo`; that *value* has been declared `const`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes; that is exactly what it means.

Since there is always a little confusion about `const` when using pointers, there are the following possibilities:

- `const T * aConstant`

  means `aConstant` is a **variable pointer** to a `constant T`.
- `T const * aConstant`

  does exactly the same.
- `T * const aConstant`

  declares that `aConstant` is a **constant pointer** to a `variable T` and.
- `T const * const aConstant` (or `const T * const aConstant`)

  declares a **constant pointer** to a `constant T`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a const pointer-to-const T. So if T was an int, then array is a pointer to an int that is const in two ways:

pointer-to-const: the value that the pointer is pointing to cannot be changed (or pointing to const int)
const pointer: the memory address stored in the pointer cannot change

This is also the same as `T const * const array`

See [wiki on const correctness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, foo is a constant pointer to constant T.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

---

```
const T*
```

makes the elements of the array `const`... at least, as far as `foo` is concerned.

```
foo[0] = T(); // Illegal!
foo[1] = T(); // Illegal!
foo[2] = whatever; // Illegal!
```

---

```
const
```

makes `foo` a constant pointer. Therefore, this is illegal:

```
foo = &some_array;
```

---

The variable

```
foo
```

...if you don't know what this is, you should seriously consider going to preschool.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley No worries, just switch the descriptions. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, i think name of var(const) is what stumbles you.

Comment: Could any of the syntax be swapped around and still preserve the meaning?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it just simply means that not only can't you change what `foo` points to, but you also can't change the value of `foo` itself so that it points to some other `T` instance.

Answer (score 0):

simply parse it like this

```
const<ptr<const<T>>> foo
```

although it is illegal, but I think everyone can grasp its essence.